# Why Savedinstance values get null when returning back to that activity in Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-savedstate

I created an application which gets values from previous activity as extras and uses that values in that activity. And the values are then sent to another activity. But when I returned back from the moving activity to previous activity the extra values are becoming null.

For example, I get Values from **Activity A** to **Activity B** (some id and image id etc) Now, I sent that values to **Activity C** as Intent extras. Here in **Activity C**, I get the values (Initial Case)! Now when I press back to  **Activity B** and Again moved to **Activity C**, I am not getting the values(some id and image id etc) in **Activity C**. This Happens in Marshmallow only. In **Activity C** name is getting from Server in **Activity B** and is Moved accordingly! This is working perfectly till lollipop!  But this happens in Marshmallow!

My Activity B Fetchservices (Here it moves to another Activity code is:

```
 public void fetchServices(){
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String userid = prefs.getString("userId","0");
        Log.e("USERID",userid);
        Log.e("URL TOP UP", Constants.BASE_URL_SERVICE_LIST+"?deviceid="+android_id+"&userid="+userid +"&country="+countryname+"&countryid="+countryid);
        RestClientHelper.getInstance().get(Constants.BASE_URL_SERVICE_LIST+"?deviceid="+android_id+"&userid="+userid+"&country="+countryname+"&countryid="+countryid, new RestClientHelper.RestClientListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                Log.e("Resposnse",response);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                parseResult(response);
                mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                        //Get item at position
                        GridItem item = (GridItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        String myactivity = "com.mobeeloadpartner."+item.getGlobalActivity();
                        if(item.getGlobalActivity().equals("0") || item.getGlobalActivity() == null || ("").equals(item.getGlobalActivity())){
                            activity =  Constants.getActivityClass("ComingSoon");
                        }
                        else{
                            activity =  Constants.getActivityClass(item.getGlobalActivity());
                        }
                            Intent intent = new Intent(GlobalActivity.this, activity);
                            Log.e("Activity",item.getGlobalActivity());
                            intent.putExtra("country", countryname);
                            intent.putExtra("countryid", countryid);
                            intent.putExtra("countrycode", countrycode);
                            intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
                            intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());
                            intent.putExtra("serviceid", item.getServiceId());
                            //Start details activity
                            startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Activity C onCreate Code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.international_topup);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        prefs = new PreferenceHelper(InternationalTopup.this);
        loading = (CircleProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading);
        check = new CheckInterNetConnection(InternationalTopup.this);
        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        mGridData = new ArrayList<>();
        mGridAdapter = new EloadGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_eload_amount, mGridData);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(InternationalTopup.this);
        isInternetPresent = check.isConnectingToInternet();

        popup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup);
        maintable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.maintable);
        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
        noOps = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.noOps);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null) {
                countryname =null;
                countryid = null;
                countrycode = null;
            } else {
                countryname= extras.getString("country");
                countryid= extras.getString("countryid");
                countrycode= extras.getString("countrycode");
            }
        } else {
            countryname= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("country");
            countryid= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("countryid");
            countrycode = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("countrycode");
        }

        opimage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.opimage);
        try {
            countryid = countryid.toLowerCase();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            countryid = "0";
        }
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Constants.URL+"/app/countries/png250px/"+countryid+".png").fit().error(R.drawable.mobeeloadicon).into(opimage);
        amount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount);
        amount.setText("0");
        EditText mytext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phonenumber);
       // mytext.setText(countrycode);
        EditText code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.code);
        code.setText(countrycode);
        code.setKeyListener(null);
        mytext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                operatorName = "Auto Fetch";
                mGridAdapter.clear();
            }
        });

        amount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                localValue = "";
            }
        });
        TextView countryName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countryname);
        countryName.setText(countryname);

        //amount.setEnabled(false);
        if (isInternetPresent) {
        } else {
            Constants.showAlert(InternationalTopup.this,"Please check your internet connection and try again");
           // SnackbarManager.show(Snackbar.with(InternationalTopup.this).text("Please check your internet connection and try again"));
        }

    }
```

Please help to sought out this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah!! That was a silly mistake! In developer option, there was an option to remove activity data when moving to activities! It was ON somehow! Keep it OFF!